# eIteration over pandas dataframe index

Tags: pandas, loops, for-loop, indexing

I want to iterate over a list (tokens), and if a specific token is contained within the list tokens, then I want to assign a value on a pandas dataframe column. My task can be seen in the following lines of code:

```
def set_party(tokens):
    democrat_kwrds = ['clinton', ... etc]
    republican_kwrds = ['trump', ... etc]
    for i, tweet in enumerate(tokens):
        dem = False
        rep = False
        print(tweet)
        for word in tweet:
            if word in democrat_kwrds:
                dem = True
            elif word in republican_kwrds:
                rep = True
            print(word)
    if dem and not rep:
        df_cleaned.loc[i,'party'] = 'dem'
    elif not dem and rep:
        df_cleaned.loc[i,'party'] = 'rep'
    else:
        df_cleaned.loc[i,'party'] = 'Nothing'
```

my problem is that I get nothing in the column('party') of `df_cleaned` at the end of iteration.
I removed `.loc[i]` and run the code,
then the function assigns 'Nothing' to the 'party' column of `df_cleaned` which is the correct answer considering the first row of the list tokens. So I assume the function works ok and it is an indexing problem.
Does anybody have any ideas?

tokens is a list of strings, here an example:

```
print(tokens[0]):
```

['think', 'ashamed', 'stand', 'pervert', 'husband', 'like']

Comment: Can you share an example of your token table and its structure ? It will be helpful before any answer
At first sight, you may consider using a lambda apply for this task. It seems more suitable for your use case and way of thinking this problem. You are working row by row so you have no need to handle iloc and indexes.

Comment: I can already tell that you if/elif/else block is not in your for block. You shout increase the indent level

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem.